# Hide get parameters from generated URL

Tags: php, get

I have a form that is submitted via GET, because I need it to generate an unique URL for each submitted form. The current generated URL looks like the example below:

http://example.com/index.php?StoreID=1&value=22000&orderID=HEQ6FMYH&option1=0&option2=0

```
<form name="form1" action="http://example.com/index.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="storeID" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="value" value="22000" />
    <input type="text" name="orderID" value="<?php echo string_random(8);?>" />
    <input type="text" name="option1" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="option2" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" />  
</form>
```

What I need to do is hide the get parameters from the generated URL. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why not use POST instead of GET ?

Comment: Why do you have to hide it? You cannot load one URL using GET and display another URL to the user. If you use a POST, only the base URL will  be displayed

Comment: This screams design flaw to me.  The whole point of submitting values through a query string is that they're visible and able to be changed by the end user.  If that's not what you want, then POST is your best bet.  You can always attach the options to some sort of identifier on the back end.

Comment: @YannickY i would guess because of the unique url...
only thing which comes to mind would be hide it in a frameset

Comment: @KevinM1 The real reason to use GET or POST is that GET should not modify anything and POST is expected to modify a resource.

Comment: @Rufinus, then my next question is, why does he need the URL to be unique, maybe something needs to be done in that regard? security concerns ?

Comment: @JuanMendes that's true.  HTTP verbs should be used in a RESTful way.  In more pragmatic terms, however, I was merely trying to point out that if one doesn't want data in the URL, they shouldn't use the one verb that puts the data there.

Comment: @KevinM1 I understand you're trying to solve the OP's problem. I'm just saying everyone should at least understand REST instead of just saying GET is for params on the URL and POST is for hiding parameters

Comment: I need to use GET instead of POST because admin will generate the link and forward It to his costumer by email. And his costumer will access it from another computer in another time. It's not possible using post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the form to a POST, and add your unique string to the action. Now all the form data will be absent from the URL, but will be passed to the receiving page, and the resulting URL itself will be unique.

```
<form name="form1" action="http://example.com/index.php?orderID=<?php echo string_random(8);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="storeID" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="value" value="22000" />
    <input type="text" name="option1" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="option2" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" />  
</form>
```

Comment: This could be what the OP wants, I can't tell since the question is not very clear. Not sure if the OP wants the random number to be displayed (they may)

Comment: I've added a randon variable inside the action and used POST. Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use POST as others suggested. 
You can also use Apache to solve the problem.
You need a .htaccess file to create in the root.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php /index.php?StoreID=$1&value=$2&orderID=$3&option1=$4&option2=$5 [NC]
```

Here you can find useful things about the mod_rewrite:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/

But as I said previously, change GET to POST and you're done:

```
<form name="form1" action="http://example.com/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="storeID" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="value" value="22000" />
    <input type="text" name="orderID" value="<?php echo string_random(8);?>" />
    <input type="text" name="option1" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="option2" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" />  
</form>
```